# Reusing the same contextMenu xml for ContextMenuMailItem and ContextMenuMultipleItems

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin, ribbon

When adding items to a context menu (ribbon) in a VSTO outlook add-in (for Outlook 2009+), is there a way to use the same context menu for multiple idMso (i.e., I'd like to add the same items for when single or multiple emails are selected)? I tried the xml below, but the schema doesn't like that I'm re-using the same button id in multiple places.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <contextMenus>
    <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuMailItem">
      <button id="DoThis"
          label="Label"
          onAction="DoThis"
          getVisible="GetVisible"/>
    </contextMenu>
    <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuMultipleItems">
      <button id="DoThis"
          label="Label"
          onAction="DoThis"
          getVisible="GetVisible"/>
    </contextMenu>
  </contextMenus>  
</customUI>
```

Ideally I guess I'd like something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <contextMenus>
    <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuMailItem,ContextMenuMultipleItems">
      <button id="DoThis"
          label="Label"
          onAction="DoThis"
          getVisible="GetVisible"/>
    </contextMenu>
  </contextMenus>  
</customUI>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reusing `id` attribute is not possible, but there is another attribute that is reusable - `tag`:

```
<button id="DoThis1" tag="DoThis" ... />
<button id="DoThis2" tag="DoThis" />
```

Then in the code then you can determine the command not by `Id` but by `Tag` property of the control.

Comment: You dont even need the Tag in that case. As you said, the id has to be different but you can have the same onAction Attribute on both buttons.